# html.actionlink? to view list of users

Tags: asp.net, html.actionlink

```
<%:Html.Actionlink(Model.User.Count().ToString, " " )
```

The code sets a actionlink on count. But when i click on the count it should show the list of users.

for ex:

if the count is 5

a click on 5 should dsiplay those 5 users on the list how set up the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the text of the link is a string when you pass it into `ActionLink`. Maybe it was a typo but `Actionlink` (lowercase L) is not an extension method on `HtmlHelper`.

```
<%:Html.ActionLink(Model.User.Count().ToString(), "Details") %>
```

[LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493018.aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName
)
```

Answer (score 0):

select any of the following ways:

1- Use the `ToString()` method after the count() method

2- Get the count on a variable:

```
<%: var count = Model.User.Count().ToString() %>
```

then in the destination area, use the code as follow:

```
<%:Html.Actionlink(count, "Details" )%>
```